# Chart.js legendcallback

Tags: chart.js

So I am having an issue with `legendcallback`, I've tried to use the template and make some changes to the HTML it doesn't use the custom template, I go off the template out the box and not the custom template.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: SetData,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    userCallback: function (value, index, values) {

                        return addCommas(value);
                    }
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    legendCallback: function (chart) {
        var legendHtml = [];
        legendHtml.push('<table>');
        legendHtml.push('<tr>');
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
            legendHtml.push('<td><div class="chart-legend" style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '"></div></       td>');
            if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                legendHtml.push('<td class="chart-legend-label-text">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</td>');
            }
        }
        legendHtml.push('</tr>');
        legendHtml.push('</table>');
        return legendHtml.join("");
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a JSFiddle that has the solution I am looking for but with something missing that I am trying to achieve. I want to append to each legend. So if the legend prints "UUV" I want to append to that with a location to identify the user of the invoice type that is. Something like "UUV" + "Chassis". Lets say what we are appending to it is the Invoice type, and I have a variable called " var InvoiceTypes" and we pass it objects and we will most likely use a condition to know which location code like "UUV" matches its Invoice type then append the invoice type to the location code.

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"> <% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) {%> <li><span style=\"background-
color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span> <%if(segments[i].label){%>
 <%=segments[i].label%>    <% } %> </li> <%}%> </ul>"
    }

    // PIE
    // PROPERTY TYPE DISTRIBUTION
    // context
    var ctxPTD = $("#property_types").get(0).getContext("2d");
    // data
    var dataPTD = [
        {
            label: "Single Family Residence",
            color: "#5093ce",
            highlight: "#78acd9",
            value: 52
        },
        {
            label: "Townhouse/Condo",
            color: "#c7ccd1",
            highlight: "#e3e6e8",
            value: 12
        },
```